# Is it possible to have a two parameter base case for a variadic member function template?

Tags: c++, c++11, variadic-templates

Consider following code:

```
class Foo {
public:
    template<typename X, typename T, typename ... Args> static void f( );
    //template<typename X, typename T> static void f( );
    template<typename X> static void f( );
};

template<typename X> void Foo::f( ) {
    cout << "Swallowed the last argument." << endl;
}

/*
template<typename X, typename T> void Foo::f( ) {
    cout << "Swallowed last two arguments." << endl;
}
 */

template<typename X, typename T, typename ... Args> void Foo::f( ) {
    cout << sizeof (T ) << endl;
    Foo::f <X, Args...>( );
}


...
    Foo::f<void*, int, double, long>( );
...
```

This works fine and the output is:

```
4
8
8
Swallowed the last argument.
```

However in the specific problem I am working on, I would like to stop the recursion one level before, as shown in the commented out code. When those lines are not commented out I get the error (gcc 4.8.3):

```
g++ -Wall -std=c++1y -march=native -fmessage-length=0 -Wno-multichar   -g  -c -o obj/OneOff/OneOff.o OneOff/OneOff.cpp
OneOff/OneOff.cpp: In instantiation of ‘static void Foo::f() [with X = void*; T = double; Args = {long int}]’:
OneOff/OneOff.cpp:132:23:   required from ‘static void Foo::f() [with X = void*; T = int; Args = {double, long int}]’
OneOff/OneOff.cpp:137:36:   required from here
OneOff/OneOff.cpp:132:23: error: call of overloaded ‘f()’ is ambiguous
  Foo::f <X, Args...>( );
                       ^
OneOff/OneOff.cpp:132:23: note: candidates are:
OneOff/OneOff.cpp:130:58: note: static void Foo::f() [with X = void*; T = long int; Args = {}]
 template<typename X, typename T, typename ... Args> void Foo::f( ) {
                                                          ^
OneOff/OneOff.cpp:125:39: note: static void Foo::f() [with X = void*; T = long int]
 template<typename X, typename T> void Foo::f( ) {
                                       ^
gmake: *** [obj/OneOff/OneOff.o] Error 1
```

**Is it possible to somehow tell the compiler that the two parameter version is a specialization / base case. E.g. use something like < .. , typename Args = {}>?**

One alternative I found was to change f() to:

```
template<typename X, typename T, typename ... Args> void Foo::f( ) {
    cout << sizeof (T ) << endl;
    if ( sizeof ...( Args ) > 1 ) {
        Foo::f <X, Args...>( );
    } else {
        cout << "Swallowed last two arguments." << endl;
    }
}
```

This gives the desired result and probably once individual variations are generated the 'if ... elses' gets optimized away along with the base case. However it looks like a bit of a hack.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Option #1

Let the variadic version take at least three fixed type template parameters:

```
template <typename X, typename T, typename V, typename... Args>
static void f();

// ...

template <typename X, typename T, typename V, typename... Args>
void Foo::f()
{
    Foo::f<X, V, Args...>( );
}
```

[**DEMO 1**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/2c694cf4042e84bf)

#### Option #2

Disable the variadic version with SFINAE if the size of a pack equals 0:

```
#include <type_traits>

template <typename X, typename T, typename... Args>
static auto f()
    -> typename std::enable_if<(sizeof...(Args) > 0)>::type;

//...

template <typename X, typename T, typename... Args>
auto Foo::f()
    -> typename std::enable_if<(sizeof...(Args) > 0)>::type
{
    Foo::f<X, Args...>( );
}
```

[**DEMO 2**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/0029692e881ad22d)

Answer (score 1):

A very simple option would be to add an additional template parameter to the recursive case so that it is only selected when there are at least three arguments:

```
class Foo {
public:
    template<typename X, typename T, typename U, typename ... Args> static void f( );
    template<typename X, typename T> static void f( );
};


template<typename X, typename T> void Foo::f( ) {
    cout << "Swallowed last two arguments." << endl;
}

template<typename X, typename T, typename U, typename ... Args> void Foo::f( ) {
    cout << sizeof (T ) << endl;
    Foo::f <X, U, Args...>( );
}
```

[<kbd>Live demo</kbd>](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/451c9c3740a14652)